# Why is a boolean value considered compatible with a class instance?

Tags: typescript

I'm not sure why the following snippet of code works...

```
class GroupLeader { /* snip */ };
function foo(leader: GroupLeader): void { /* snip: do stuff */ }

const isLeader = false;
const groupLeader = isLeader && new GroupLeader();

foo(groupLeader);
```

In the REPL, I can see `groupLeader` ends up being a `boolean` type, but there is no error generated by TypeScript compiler (version 4.4.3) when invoking `foo(groupLeader)`.

**Why does this work?**

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEDiBOB7ArgBwDIFMwBNP2gG9oB6AKmggDsBLVaMk6AXwG4AoAM2SuABcaiKtE6JEAChDY88AFxwkaLLnwBKeQDdENHEVIVqdeTkSU+yTpwZNm7dsCEQ+0GhGUzoAXhFgQETBwOVE7QAOaKGNL4Xi5uUQQAZAnQVJgA7gookSrw4qocXGLi4VnuahxAA)

Comment: And if you put anything into the class, an error is generated as expected - eg `class GroupLeader { x = 5 };`

Comment: It’s not a bug, TS has structural typing, so empty classes behave like empty object types: only `null` and `undefined` are not assignable to them.  See [Why do these empty classes behave strangely? from the TypeScript FAQ](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-do-these-empty-classes-behave-strangely.)  Also see [the handbook documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#relationships-between-classes) starting with "Empty classes have no members..."

Comment: You could simplify your example code by just calling `foo(false)` directly, and observing that there is no error.

Answer (score 7):

This is the expected behavior in TypeScript.

TypeScript's type system is largely [*structural*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structural_type_system) as opposed to [*nominal*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nominal_type_system).  So it's the *shape* or *structure* of a type that matters, and not its *name* or *declaration*.  So the TypeScript compiler can decide that type `A` is a *subtype* of `B` (or "`A` is *assignable* to `B`" or "`A` *extends* `B`") whether or not you mention `A` anywhere in the declaration of `B`.  It only matters if the apparent properties of `B` have compatible properties in `A`:

```
interface A {
    x: string;
    y: number;
}

interface B {
    x: string;
}

const a: A = { x: "", y: 0 };
const b: B = a; // okay, A extends B
```

The last line is not an error like it would be in a nominally typed language.

---

Note that "apparent property" means that even some [primitives](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Primitive) like `number`, `string`, and `boolean` can be considered structurally compatible with object types, because JavaScript [automatically wraps some primitives in wrapper objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Primitive#primitive_wrapper_objects_in_javascript) when you index into them.  So the type `{length: number}` is a subtype of `string`:

```
interface L { length: number };
const l: L = "hello"; // okay
```

because `string` values have an apparent `length` property of type `number`.

---

In TypeScript, [`class`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html) declarations [are also treated structurally in general](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#relationships-between-classes) (although there are some cases where nominal-like typing happens, such as [using `instanceof` to distinguish between two classes](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-7.html#improved-handling-of-structurally-identical-classes-and-instanceof-expressions) or when you [add `private` or `protected` members](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html#private-and-protected-members-in-classes)).  So if you have an empty class:

```
class GroupLeader { }
```

This class is structurally identical to the empty object type `{}`, an object type with no members.  And so *any* value which can be indexed into like an object will be seen as assignable to that class:

```
function foo(leader: GroupLeader): void { /* snip: do stuff */ }

foo(true); // okay
foo(123); // okay
foo({}); // okay
foo(() => 3); // okay
foo(new Date()); // okay
foo(Symbol("oops")); // okay

foo(null); // error
foo(undefined); // error
```

Only `null` and `undefined` are not assignable to `GroupLeader`, because `null` and `undefined` throw runtime errors if you index into them like an object.

---

So that's why it's happening.  Generally you want to prevent such behavior, so empty classes and empty object types are best avoided, even in example code.  The (somewhat outdated) [TypeScript FAQ](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ) has a bunch of entries around this, like [Why are all types assignable to empty interfaces?](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-are-all-types-assignable-to-empty-interfaces) and [Why do these empty classes behave strangely?](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-do-these-empty-classes-behave-strangely).  If you want the compiler to treat two types as distinct, you should make sure they have incompatible shapes.

Adding any property that `boolean` doesn't share to `GroupLeader` will change things:

```
class GroupLeader { unsnip = 0 };

function foo(leader: GroupLeader): void { /* snip: do stuff */ }
foo(true); // error
foo(123); // error
foo({}); // error
foo(() => 3); // error
foo(new Date()); // error
foo(Symbol("oops")); // error

foo(new GroupLeader()); // okay
```

Of course the possibility still exists that something structurally compatible will be passed in:

```
foo({ unsnip: 123 }); // okay
```

You can try to prevent this if you want (a `private` property will do it) but the path of least resistance is to just write code that only cares about structural compatibility.  Whatever `foo()`'s implementation is, it should only care about the *structure* of `leader` and not the *declaration*.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgILIN4FgBQz-IAeAXMgM5hSgDmA3LgcgJ6kgCuAtgEbT04C+uXKEixEKAEKYGBEuUo0+gnLgQB7EBWRxS6ALyYipAETGANM1IAGZPz7rNYZF1JSDcWsgD0X5GoDWcEwW6BCEkCAAJmTIEkIqOCLQ8EjIADKGADYQINRgABasnDxQtvYaWpmkGQbG+RCZmWrGnj5+gUzxIHAcEGQADuLIAPJq-THYeAQImXBkMQDiUGps-WkQcJHQhl4AVOQgwP3Iu7528TL4MGwgCGDAGsgwamoAFNmb0KRLK2sbW1AAJSkABuamAkR2+zIh36pEiankbBgMBOZ0uTxer0obAggNavgCQQxzzeAEYAEwAZnx3kJHRJWIw-FpbSJnSmVyxr0ByD0AD5kDSCe1iZzMW8QBAAO7IAAicEgPNZ9LFjFJrwAykxuGpMq9jC9xsZASrRRzGZK2I0zdBllBLa8blsYKAIJFbVB7fFlF0en1BqkAGLAQjScUzOaLZardafUoYZA3GFHPnIGznBIkm53B4gCXvf5fZA-WNFoGg8GQxN7A5HeGIijI1GnWyOnF4kV2tQO8UaynCunIbu99VMlldr09x08vmCwdtEeOqWyhVK02T719rHa3X6w1jMgmz1b5cyksxv7x5Ui9mOxPJ2GkAe2M13hK+hJAA)